# como hacer que un array vaya adelante sin un contador?

Tags: javascript, array, while

hace poco encontré un código que me servía para generar números casuales sin repetirse, pero no entiendo como el que lo escribió hace que el array vaya para adelantes sin contador.

este es el código:

```js
//Define la cantidad de numeros aleatorios.
var cantidadNumeros = 5;
var myArray = []
while(myArray.length < cantidadNumeros ){
  var numeroAleatorio = Math.ceil(Math.random()*cantidadNumeros);
  var existe = false;
  for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray [i] == numeroAleatorio){
        existe = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!existe){
    myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;
  }

}
document.write("números aleatorios : " + myArray);
```

Comment: a que te refieres con "que el array vaya para adelante sin contador"... a que te refieres con que vaya para adelante?

Comment: Pero si está recorriendo el array con un `for`... Por favor, leé [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Javascript hace un control automático de los arrays, si usas una posición que no ha sido declarada, la crea automáticamente.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var cosas=[];
console.log(cosas);
cosas[5]="algo";
console.log(cosas);
```

Verás que primero el array esta vació, pero al incluir un elemento en la posición 5, automáticamente se incluyen las posiciones anteriores.
De manera que se pueden usar directamente las posiciones de un array aunque no se hayan declarado o inicializado, y es lo que pasa en tu ejemplo, añade el elemento en la última posición +1

Las posiciones de un array van de [0] a [lenght-1], así que en esta línea:

```
myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;
```

Está introduciendo un elemento "por el final" del array.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var cosas=["a","b","c"];
console.log("cosas: "+cosas);
console.log("Hay "+cosas.length+" elementos, del [0] al ["+(cosas.length-1)+"]");
console.log("Introducimos un elemento en la posición ["+cosas.length+"]");
cosas[cosas.length]="d";
console.log("cosas: "+cosas);
```

Answer (score 0):

No es que el arreglo vaya *"hacia delante"*, sino que se especifica el total de elementos que va a contener y se hace un ciclo para agregarlos:

```
while(myArray.length < cantidadNumeros ) {
    /* Instrucciones */
}
```

Este ciclo se va a estar ejecutando mientras la cantidad de elementos del arreglo sea menor que la especificada en `cantidadNumeros`; cada nuevo elemento se agrega con `myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;` que está dentro del condicional en la última parte del ciclo.

En resumen, lo que hace este fragmento de código es generar un arreglo de números desde 1 hasta el especificado en `cantidadNumeros` (5), pero en orden aleatorio.

Agregué algunos comentarios para explicar qué se hace en cada paso:

```js
//Define la cantidad de numeros aleatorios.
let cantidadNumeros = 5;
let myArray = [];
// Variable para saber qué tan eficiente es este proceso
let pasos = 0;
// Ejecutar mientras el arreglo no tenga la cantidad de elementos especificada
while(myArray.length < cantidadNumeros ){
  // Obtener número aleatorio entre uno y la cantidad de elementos
  let numeroAleatorio = Math.ceil(Math.random()*cantidadNumeros);
  // Inicializar variable para saber si el número ya está en el arreglo o no
  let existe = false;
  // Recorrer elementos actuales para analizar
  for(let i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    // ¿Ya existe el número en el arreglo?
    if(myArray [i] == numeroAleatorio){
        // Marcar como existente y dejar de recorrer
        existe = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  // ¿No existe el número en el arreglo?
  if(!existe){
    // Insertar
    myArray[myArray.length] = numeroAleatorio;
  }
  pasos ++;
}
console.log("números aleatorios : " + myArray);
// En el mejor de los casos, deberían ser 5 pasos
// Pero en las pruebas obtuve hasta 14 pasos para obtener 5 números
console.log('Pasos: ' + pasos);
```

Una solución más adecuada sería generar el arreglo con los números en orden y ejecutar una función para desordenarlos:

```js
/**
 * Función para desordenar un arreglo
 * Tomada de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array/6274381#6274381
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    let j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

// Definir la cantidad de números y el arreglo
let cantidadNumeros = 5;
let arr = [];

// Ejecutar ciclo de 1 hasta la cantidad deseada
for(let i = 1; i <= cantidadNumeros; i++) {
    // Agregar números en orden
    arr.push(i);
}
// Arreglo ordenado
console.log(arr);

// Desordenar
shuffle(arr);

// Arreglo desordenado
console.log(arr);
```

**Nota:** Función para desordenar tomada de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array/6274381#6274381) (en inglés).